# Trying to solve $\int{\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}}$ using trigonometric substitution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have been trying to solve the following task:
Find the area $A$ bounded by the curves $y = \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}$, $y = 0$ and lying over interval above $[2, \infty)$.

So I have to solve $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} \, dx$

Obviously you can solve it using partial fractions, but I know it should also be possible by trigonometric substitution. I tried to use such substitution.

[image: I used this triangle]

$$ \tan{u} = \sqrt{x^2 - 1},\, \Big(-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq u \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \Big) $$
$$ \cos{u} = \frac{1}{x} \\ \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{\cos u} $$
$$ dx = \tan{u} \sec{u} \, du $$
$$ x = 2 \Rightarrow u = \frac{\pi}{3},\,\, x \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow u \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2} \\ $$
$$ \int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2} \, dx = \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \frac{\tan{u} \sec{u}}{\tan^2{u}} \, du = \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \csc{u} \,\\ du = \big[ -\ln|\csc{u} + \cot{u}| \big]_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} $$
$$ = - \bigg[\ln{1} - \ln {\Bigg|\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \Bigg|} \bigg] = \ln{\sqrt{3}} $$

But the result using partial fractions is $ \frac{1}{3} - \frac{\ln{3}}{4}$.

I'm not sure where is my mistake, I think this substitution is wrong, but I have no idea why. I know that it is suspicious to use this type of substitution in indefinit integral, because of domain, but here we are dealing with positive values of $x$.

If the substitution is wrong, then is it possible to use different trigonometric substitution here?

Comment: $(x^2-1)^2 = \tan^4 u$.

Comment: Thank you, I made a silly mistake

Comment: You could also consider hyperbolic substitution: $x=\tanh{(x)}$.

Comment: What about $x=\sec(u)?$

Comment: Alternatively, $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}$ to get an integrand with a much simpler partial fraction expansion.